# UITableView Headers with UTF-8 Strings?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm formatting my UITableView headers with Unix %s formatting because the Objective C format code %@ doesn't handle padding (e.g. %20@%20s).  Unfortunately, if I have accented foreign characters, they aren't displayed properly.  The word "voilà" appears like this:

[image]

Here's how I generate my table header:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    ...
    //NSString *tblHdr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%12s", @"voilà"]; 
    NSString *tblHdr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%12s", [@"voilà" UTF8String]]; // Fixed example
    ...
    return tblHdr;
}
```

[Update]

Here's the actual code from my project.  I tried to keep it simple in my original example:

```
        tblHdr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-45s%12s%12s%35s",
                  [NSLocalizedString(@"Quiz Name", @"") UTF8String],
                  [NSLocalizedString(@"Correct", @"")  UTF8String],
                  [NSLocalizedString(@"Missed", @"")  UTF8String],
                  [NSLocalizedString(@"Score", @"")  UTF8String]
                  ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `%s` format expects a C string in the system encoding,
so this works

```
NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%12s", [@"voilá" cStringUsingEncoding:enc]];
```

(as long as the string can be represented in the system encoding).

Otherwise you can pad the string manually:

```
NSString *t = @"voilá";
if ([t length] < 12) {
    t = [[@"" stringByPaddingToLength:(12 - [t length]) withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:t];
}
```

(or use @Daij-Djan's method, which was posted while I wrote this).

Comment: stringByPaddingToLength looks better suited than my crude loop

Answer (score 1):

1. issue: %s formats a char* which is != NSString. so:

`NSString *tblHdr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%12s", @"voilà".UTF8String];`

This doesn't work as %s seems to not do multibyte right IMO!? Not sure

I'd stick with NSStrings... just add the spaces manually

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //wrong
        NSString *tblHdr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%12s", @"voilà".UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"%@", tblHdr);       

        //ok
        NSMutableString *rawTblHdr = @"voilà".mutableCopy;
        while(12-rawTblHdr.length) {
            [rawTblHdr insertString:@" " atIndex:0];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", rawTblHdr);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's what my real project looks like @"%-45s%12s%12s%35s".  Using real spaces is painful.

Comment: then do what martin proposed and call a deprecated method :( sorry

Comment: @Daij-Djan: The deprecated method has been replaced.

Comment: ah cool. i only tried cStringUsingEncoding with a UTF8 encoding which was pointless. nice!